# *ngFor doesn't show any data

Tags: angular

All questions related to this weren't getting a JSON in the first place.

I want to print a list of demands with ngFor. It doesn't show anything.

This is my html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of DemandasList">
  {{item.demandaName}}
</div>
```

This is my demandas.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DemandasService } from './demandas.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demandas',
  templateUrl: './demandas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demandas.component.css'],
  providers: [DemandasService]
})
export class DemandasComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:DemandasService, private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  DemandasList:any=[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshDemList();
  }

  refreshDemList() {
    this.service.getDemList().subscribe(data=> {
      this.DemandasList=data;
      console.log(this.DemandasList);
    });
  }
```

The console.log prints this:
[Console results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvq6c.png)

this is the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DemandasService {
readonly APIUrl="http://localhost:3440/api"

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 

  }

  getDemList():Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl+'/demandas');
  }
}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misspelled `DemandasList`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of DemandasList">
  {{item.demandaName}}
</div>
```

---

**Optional**:

If You want I would suggest your code refactor.

Declare `DemandasList` as `Observable`

```
demandasList$:Observable<any[]>;
```

If want to start with an empty array

```
demandasList$:Observable<any[]> = of([]);
```

Assign demandasList$ to a service call in ngOninit

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.demandasList$ = this.service.getDemList();
  // to console.log
  // this.demandasList$ = this.service.getDemList().pipe(tap(console.log));
}
```

In template use [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe to subscribe/unsubscribe

```
<div *ngFor="let item of DemandaList$ | async">
  {{item.demandaName}}
</div>
```

If you want to show div on conditional

```
<div *ngIf="DemandaList$ | async as DemandaList; else loading">
    <div *ngFor="let item of DemandaList">
      {{item.demandaName}}
    </div>
</div>

<ng-template #loading>
    <div>Loading ...</div>
</ng-template>
```

Imports used

```
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: I wrote the div for the question (actual usage is a mat card), hence why the typo, but it doesnt work anyway. I'll do the refactoring.